# Lining up percentage based divs within a horizontal bar graph?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a horizontal HTML bar graph and having some issues wrapping my head around the layout. Basically I want to have a div with a background image with 10, evenly spaced, vertical lines and then have several divs within that div with percentage-based widths.

Functionally, everything is working as expected, but I am having a difficult time figuring out how to get the bars to line up with the vertical lines in the background image.

For instance, if a bar has a width of 60% it should align with the 6th vertical line.

HTML:

```
<div class="chart">
    <div class="bar-container">
        <div data-percentage="70" class="bar">Product 1</div>
        <div data-percentage="30" class="bar">Product 2</div>
        <div data-percentage="90" class="bar">Product 3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.chart {
    width:320px;
    height:200px;
    background-image:url('http://s15.postimg.org/ku83p3fvf/bars.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:contain;
    position: relative;
}
    .chart .bar-container {
        position:absolute;
        bottom:30px;
        width:100%;
    }
        .chart .bar-container .bar {
            background:#55565a;
            margin-top:5px;
            color:#fff;
            font-size:16px;
            padding:2px 0;
        }
```

Javascript:

```
$('.bar').each(function() {
    percentage = $(this).attr('data-percentage');
    $(this).css('width',percentage+'%');
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uy6bnrmx/)

Any ideas what I'm overlooking here?

Comment: I think the problem is, you have 9 bars not 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your background image as a division of NINE bars, not TEN. As such, you have to do some math to make the widths match up. Or, you can make the image 10 bars instead of nine. [Heres a fixed JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yzvvb1zL/), notice the math done in the Jquery part

```
$('.bar').each(function() {
    percentage = $(this).attr('data-percentage');
    $(this).css('width',percentage / .9 +'%');
});
```

Comment: WOW! Can't believe I overlooked that, thank you so much, been scratching my head on this for quite some time.

Comment: @user13286 It's always the simple things :P Happy to help!